# How to compare now to a timestamp in Mysql, when greater than 1, else 0

Tags: mysql

How to compare now to a timestamp in Mysql, when valid_date is greater than now 1, else 0?

I only have data of `valid_date`, I need data of `is_valid`, thanks so much for any advice.

```
  valid_date   is_valid
  1675739460     0
  1680837060     1
  1678190564     1
  1686365124     1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to `SELECT` a boolean result by comparing the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` with `valid_date`.

```
SELECT valid_date, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() < valid_date AS is_valid FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare a timestamp to the current time in MySQL, you can use the NOW() function, which returns the current date and time.
To create a condition where valid_date is greater than NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT IF(valid_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, 1, 0) AS is_valid FROM table;
```

You can adjust the time interval as needed by changing the value passed to INTERVAL.

Comment: Both of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).   As a heads-up, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool for assistance on this answer, could I ask you to (1) Reply in a comment here confirming that it was AI-generated, along with what tool (e.g., ChatGPT, Bing Chat, Copilot, etc.) -- We're compiling data on AI-assisted answers and could use your help. (2) After commenting, I recommend deleting your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.